# Correct using of Java memory (save and sorting 1 million raws)

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, spring-boot

I need your advice.

I have one million rows in DB ( just F.name ) I save it in ArrayList. 
Next I need sort it with regex. But it's need a lot of time. How can i make it faster ?  IMPORTANT: I need use  only java tools. Thank you for help !

This is my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", params = "nameFilter")
    @ResponseBody
    public ContactBean contacts(@RequestParam("nameFilter") String nameFilter) {
        filter.setPattern(nameFilter);
        long totalCount = contactDao.count();
        if (totalCount <= MAX) {
            return filter.filterAll();
        } else {
            return filter.startFilter(0, MAX);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/contacts", params = {"nameFilter", "page"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ContactBean contacts(@RequestParam("nameFilter") String nameFilter,
                                 @RequestParam("page") int page,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "cnt", required = false, defaultValue = "1000000") int cntPerPage) {
        filter.setPattern(nameFilter);
        if (page < 0) {
            page = 0;
        }
        if (cntPerPage > MAX || cntPerPage < 1) {
            cntPerPage = MAX;
        }
        return filter.startFilter(page, cntPerPage);
    }
}
```

And this is my filter

```
@Component("filterService")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Filter {
    private List<ContactEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Filter.class);

    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;

    private Pattern pattern;

    public void setPattern(String regex) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    private void filterIt(Iterator<ContactEntity> toFilter) {
        while(toFilter.hasNext()) {
            ContactEntity next = toFilter.next();
            if(!pattern.matcher(next.getName()).matches()) {
                result.add(next);
            }
        }
    }

    public ContactBean filterAll() {
        LOGGER.info("Start filtering for all data");
        List<ContactEntity> contacts = (List<ContactEntity>)contactDao.findAll();
        filterIt(contacts.iterator());
        ContactBean model = new ContactBean();
        model.setContacts(result);
        model.setTotalCount(contactDao.count());
        LOGGER.info("Filtering complete");
        return model;
    }

    public ContactBean startFilter(int startPage, int cntPerPage) {
        LOGGER.info("Start filtering");
        Page<ContactEntity> contacts = contactDao.findAll(new PageRequest(startPage, cntPerPage, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
        filterIt(contacts.iterator());
        ContactBean model = new ContactBean();
        model.setContacts(result);
        model.setTotalCount(contactDao.count());
        model.setCurrentPage(startPage);
        model.setTotalPage(contacts.getTotalPages());
        LOGGER.info("Filtering complete");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you let the db sort the data? What were the results?

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you edit and post only a [mcve]? And note that you have a big issue with your approach. Let's say you have 100 records and only 20 matches, don't that break your pagination?

Comment: Did you tried profiler?

Comment: efekctive, I can use only java tools =(
 RC, I will edit my post, thank  you for recommendations.

Comment: No, I didn't use profiler. I hoped that I do something stupid )

Comment: @atticus `jvisualvm` is standard java tool from `JDK`

Comment: Show us your regex and some example names. And let us know how long a lot of time takes.

Comment: for example nameFilter=^.*[aei].*$
It's take almost 10-15 seconds.

Comment: https://github.com/Viacheslav21/backend_time 
here is my rep. If somebody can check and help, I will be very thankfull